# Is there a way to cache a global as a local const in cpython?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to define a const object from a pre-existing global variable inside a function (in cpython) such that it gets loaded with the `LOAD_CONST` instruction (short of modifying and recompiling the interpreter yourself)?

Assuming the value of the global doesn’t change and we only care about setting the value at the time the function is defined—it can be a copy of the value, not a reference to it.

In other words, how could:

```py
a = 7

def f():
    return a + 1
```

be made to be synonymous with:

```py
def f():
    a = 7
    return a + 1
```

so that `7` appears in `f.__code__.co_consts` of the former and `LOAD_CONST` is used to load it?

Using python 3.11.1 for anything that involves modifying function byte code.

Comment: Could you maybe expand on _why_ you'd like to do this..?

Comment: No, Python does not provide this feature. You can, of course, use `return b + 1` to use the local reference, but since you still have to pay the cost of loading the global in the first place, you'll want to use `b` several times to amortize that cost. You could, of course, not use a global in the first place, and pass the value as an argument instead.

Comment: This smells of premature optimization, though: is the cost of accessing a global really the bottleneck in your program?

Comment: It’s for a niche use case where my module needs its own version of `None` among other things that it’ll be using in many small functions that will be called a large number of times. On the device it’ll be running on, `timeit` tells me it could save multiple seconds. The api also needs to be adhered to, so no optimizing outside of it. @AKX

Comment: Multiple seconds, out of how much total runtime? Especially since you're on Python 3.11, with the new optimizations, this seems unlikely to save a lot of time.

Comment: Depending on the use case, my timings show that this optimization can be up to 1/14 of the execution time in certain routes. This is a niche issue where global constants are used extensively in a way where the api requires small functions that load them each time. @user2357112

Comment: Maybe if the arguments are often the same, memoization with `functools.lru_cache` could be an option?

Comment: If it's a constant, just give every function that needs it its own not-otherwise-used parameter with the constant as a default.

Comment: What's your timeit code (and its results) that you tested?

Comment: Well, I think a bytecode modifier decorator can do that - but nothing short of that.

Comment: Can you just literally use `7` as your "version of `None`"? Or `8287647482736748449373664`? If not, why not?

Comment: What do you intend to use this "version of `None` for? In your example you add `1` to it, but what's `None + 1`?

Comment: If the goal is simply to improve performance, what's wrong with, say, writing `b = a` at the top and then using `b` throughout?

Comment: The values doesn't get used enough for the initial LOAD_GLOBAL calls to be amortized enough for it to be more performant @KarlKnechtel

Comment: In that case, how can this possibly be a relevant optimization?

Comment: “Version of `None`” as in a sentinel value that doesn’t conflict with the built-in `None`. I used that as an example—many similar global constants are used a significant amount in largely trivial ways where the function overhead, etc… accounts for most of the run time. @KellyBundy

Comment: So are you actually going to do something like adding `1` to it, or only compare it by `is`?

Comment: Compare with `is`—all of these would be publicly exposed and need to act as sentinels, so no regular constants could be used (that I’m aware of, at least not 16 byte large ones; it also can be an `isinstance` of anything, so an obscurely large int is off the table).

Comment: *can’t be an `isinstance` @KellyBundy

Comment: Now I want to see what object isn't `isinstance` of `object`...

Answer (score -2):

If you can make use of `inspect.get_source` (it is really smart - and will work in most real-world cases as far as the .py files are available - but it won't do with the `@` decorator syntax), here is a decorator that will insert the needed lines declaring the local variables and re-create the function.

While the code bellow is good enough, it will provide frozen copies of the function globals() at the moment the decorator is called - so even if you are not updating values, if there are more than one function and they are interdependent, the order of calling the decorator matters.

```
from functools import partial
import inspect
from types import NoneType

def freeze(func_or_args,/, args=None):
    if isinstance(func_or_args, (str, list)):
        return partial(freeze, args=func_or_args)
    func = func_or_args
    if isinstance(args, str):
        args = args.split()
    source = inspect.getsource(func)
    iter_source = iter(source.split("\n"))
    new_source = []
    # copy function definition, signature and first empty lines
    defined = False
    while True:
        line = next(iter_source)
        if not defined and line.split("#")[0].strip().endswith(":"):
            defined = True
        elif defined and line.strip():
            break
        new_source.append(line)
    indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    tabs_or_spaces = line[0]
    func_globals = func.__globals__.copy()
    for global_ in args:
        value = func_globals.get(global_)
        line_to_insert = f"{tabs_or_spaces * indent}{global_} = "
        if isinstance(value, (int, float, str, bytes, bytearray, NoneType)):
            line_to_insert += repr(value)
        else:
            line_to_insert += f"globals_.get('{global_}')"
        new_source.append(line_to_insert)
    new_source.append(line)
    new_source.extend(iter_source)
    new_source = "\n".join(new_source)
    print(new_source)
    func_globals["globals_"] = func_globals
    exec(new_source, func_globals)
    return func_globals[func.__name__]


a = 7

#@freeze("a")  # decorator syntax won't work due to the use of inspect.get_source
def blah():
    return a + 1

blah = freeze(blah, "a")

import dis
dis.dis(blah)

print(blah())
```

And this is the output I get from this file:

```
[gwidion@fedora tmp01]$ python freezenator.py 
def blah():
    a = 7
    return a + 1

  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (7)
              2 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           4 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
              8 BINARY_ADD
             10 RETURN_VALUE
8
```

I had written this initially imagining you'd have a loop in each function where re-using the variable several times in a row would actually make a larger difference when comparing to the function calling overhead.

I don't know how far the optimizations in Python 3.11 go,  but if you are trying to micro-optimize in this scale functions that have no inner loop, you likely will get a greater gain by converting them to generators instead -

```
def blah():
   b = a
   while True:
      yield b + 1
```

instantiate them wherever you have your loop and retrieve the value with `next`.

Comment: Doesn't the output show that it's doing a lot **more** instead of less?

Comment: And the variable value isn't loaded with `LOAD_CONST`, only the variable name and the `1` are.

Comment: `LOAD_FAST` should be equally interesting - and, of course, testing for an instance of a literal (float, int, str) and hardcoidng it would be trivial with this code, just add a test for that when iterating over the args. 
And - this code "is doing a lot more" - because it is test code with no inner loops in the function - a LOAD_GLOBAL would have no difference in this context as well. Repeating it a couple thousand times will.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Is that `a = globals_.get('a')` not executed every time the function is called?

Comment: yes, it is - but the optimization asked for only makes sense itself if the vriable will be accessed in a loop inside the function. Otherwise, just the function calling overhead is larger than the LOAD_GLOBALS anyway. This avoids LOAD_GLOBALS in all iterations in an inner loop.
And if the function has no loops, but is called several (thousands) times, it should be changed to work as an iterator instead to overcome that overhead - in which case this helps again

Comment: but for what you are whorring about, see that `for global_ in args: ` there? 
Just stick a `if isinstance(val:=func_globals.get(global_), (int, float, str)): line_to_insert = f"... = {val}; continue" in there.

Comment: They even rejected Karl's "writing `b = a` at the top and then using `b` throughout", which is faster than this, saying "The values doesn't get used enough for the initial LOAD_GLOBAL calls to be amortized enough for it to be more performant".

Comment: There it is: fixed to inline literals

Comment: They already said they can't use an int, not even an obscurely large one like I suggested.